# Can I prevent my career page to be indexed by search engines?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

Can I prevent my career page to be indexed by search engines please.

Edit: Just an option button will be enough. It is available in WordPress too, it is not something new.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why?

Comment: I have a unique full-name, when people search me on Google I don't want to give all my career information. I want to be seen only from the links which I will list in related web sites. It is not other peoples' job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks feasible. We'll work on it.

For reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Privacy_SubPanel

Update 11 Mar: We've implemented a basic version of this.

You will find a checkbox to "Instruct search engines not to index my profile" alongside your other preferences for job search status.

This will add a [robots noindex](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93710) meta tag, which Google and other search engines should respect.

Comment: Oh thanks, I'm very happy right now :) From now on I can use my correct last name.

Comment: Does this option keep search engines blocked if I make my careers profile public? Has it been improved since then?